# MySQLIMPORT Hex Values

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I am trying to import a CSV file into a MySQL 5.1 database.

The script for creating the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `session_hdr` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `session_start_time` decimal(20,8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_end_time` decimal(20,8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_last_update_time` decimal(20,8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_flag` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

This is the data I am tyring to import into the session_hdr table:

```
0X10004299300,1,7,1324542626.182691780,0.0,1324542627.76399180,1,3
0X1000429BF00,1,7,1324542656.188777040,0.0,1324542657.136454760,1,3
0X1000429CB00,1,7,1324542663.269024060,0.0,1324542663.292035400,1,3
0X1000429F200,1,7,1324542686.177864720,0.0,1324542687.45881600,1,3
0X100042A4000,1,7,1324542716.178234960,0.0,1324542717.645671220,1,3
0X100042A6800,1,7,1324542746.173958660,0.0,1324542747.66159900,1,3
....
```

The command I am using is to import is:

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 -c id,type,session_start_time,session_end_time,session_last_update_time,session_flag,version databaseName1 session_hdr.csv
```

When I execute the command I reveive the following message:

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1265, Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1, when using table: session_hdr
```

Does anyone see why the above command would be throwing that error?

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `0x` with a small x?

Comment: @Pekka I changed it to a lowercase x... same result. I also tried to remove the hex totally and just increment starting at 1 and that still did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data, the first colmn's value do not conform to an int type, which can only contain numbers.  You will need to convert the values from hex to int before importing.